# ¿Cómo sumar valores introducidos mostrando el primero en la caja de resultados?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al introducir algún valor en mi los input's de mi pagina se puedan sumar, pero no solo eso si no que al introducir el primer valor me lo muestre en la caja de texto de resultados este es mi código para que se den una idea y ojala me puedan ayudar,

Este es el script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copiar()
    {
        document.getElementById("resultado").value = document.getElementById("costo1").value;
    }
</script>
```

Estas son las variables que quiero sumar:

```
<input type="number" id="costo1" name="costo1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="copiar();" value="<?php echo $vcosto1; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo1" name="costo1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="sumar();" value="<?php echo $vcosto2; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo1" name="costo1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="sumar();" value="<?php echo $vcosto3; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo1" name="costo1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="sumar();" value="<?php echo $vcosto4; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías aprender algo de HTML/JS. https://www.w3schools.com/

Te resultara todo mas fácil si añades JQuery a tu pagina, por las diversas funciones de change, onready, onclick, etc...
http://api.jquery.com/

Aquí de dejo un esbozo de lo que has pedido:

```
$(".costos").change(function() {
  var suma = $("#costo1").val() + $("#costo2").val() + $("#costo3").val() + $("#costo4").val();
  $("#resultado").val(suma);
});

<input type="number" id="costo1" class="costos" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $vcosto1; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo2" class="costos" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $vcosto2; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo3" class="costos" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $vcosto3; ?>" >

<input type="number" id="costo4" class="costos" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $vcosto4; ?>" >
```